# The onload doesn't work using 'Vue-konva'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, konvajs

I am using Vue-konva for image upload site.
When I use `.onload()` with **local image path**, the onload doesn't work.
I put the `.src` before `.onload`. But the problem is the same.

```
const ImageFrame = new window.Image();

ImageFrame.onload = () => {
  const yoFrame = {
    image: ImageFrame,
    scaleX: 1,
    scaleY: 1,
    x: 10,
    y: 10
  };

  commit('pushFrameImage', yoFrame);
};

ImageFrame.src = '../../assets/frame.jpg';
```

Could you recommend some solution ?
thank you for reading this.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't get 404 error?

Comment: I didnt get any error. When I put console log inside of onload, the console log doesnt work..